# C++ how to read a key without waiting for key grip "Enter" on Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, linux, console.readkey

Personally, I think the title is clear, if not, I’ll try to be more. Only managed solutions for Windows, for Linux does not. As you well know, the method "getchar()" reads only after keyboard key grip "Enter".

The conio.h library does not exist on Linux and ncurses or curses have to use a different command at build time, which I do not think very productive.

Comment: Because the terminal buffers the input, the program does not receive the line until enter is pressed and the terminal flushes. You have to use a terminal dependent solution (just like on windows, conio.h): `ncurses` is the way to go.

Comment: @erenon But I do not understand how.

Comment: Basically you want a `getch()` alternative?

Comment: @skrtbhtngr "‘getch’ was not declared in this scope".

Comment: Your only alternative is to use the functions in ncurses library, I suppose.

Comment: @skrtbhtngr I added the ncurses.h library, but when running this line "c = getch();" gives this error:
"undefined reference to 'stdscr'";

"undefined reference to 'wgetch'"

Comment: `ncurses.h` is a header file (defining types).  You must link with the ncurses library to use the library.

Comment: @ThomasDickey But how I do it?

Answer (score 0):

fscanf on stdin would do it, I suppose.

Comment: What would it be stdin? A library? A method?

Comment: stdin means the standard input, I.e. In this case the characters you type on your keyboard

Comment: If you need to read every character and not waiting for CR/LF, then [getchar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) is most likely what you need.